# Is it possible to get all the nodes with a specific name from a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

I am converting to a PHP array from a Facebook API response in JSON format. The result is a multilevel array with many elements named `id` on every level.

I would like to retrieve all the elements with the name `id` and I was wondering if there is any direct way to get all those elements without having to parse each level of the array to grab the element.

Hope this question makes sense, 
Any tip will be much appreciated.

Comment: If it's coming from Facebook, I presume it has a decent structure to it - so you should write a script that will expect that structure and parse that structure. Make sure you use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) and don't try and parse it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Array Column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function

```
$output = array_column($input, 'id');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have php 5.5 (i.e. no `array_column` for you), you may use this:

```
$ids = array_map(function($element) {return $element['id'];}, $input);
```